# UIDatePicker combined with UITextField, didselectrow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have a simple UITextField that holds a date and I want to have a UIDatePicker pop up to be able to change the date.  I can get the date picker to pop up, but can't figure out how to access the custom cell class I set up from the @selector...?

```
    // set the text field input to the datepicker
UIDatePicker *myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
myPicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[myPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
resultscell.textEventDate.inputView = myPicker;

return resultscell;

}

-(IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"the date changed");
}
```

How in the above example would I access the resultscell.textEventDate to change it?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make a property for `UIDatePicker`, and hook up the `IBOutlet`. Then you can write something like:

```
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And then in your `dateChanged:` method you can write:

```
- (void)dateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)picker
{
    NSLog(@"Date: %@", [picker date]);
}
```

From there you can do whatever you'd like with the `NSDate` value that is given to you.